# How can we access a variable from a different area in Java

Tags: java

Is there a way to access a variable (Example one marked by a comment consisting of *** next to it) in a different area (Marked by %%% in comment). I have looked around for ways to do this but can't really find anything or understand it well enough.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Program extends Display {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        display.setSize(1600, 800);
        display.setResizable(false);
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Main Menu
        JButton select = new JButton("Select");
        select.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        JButton absent = new JButton("Absentees");
        absent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        absent.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        exit.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        exit.setLocation(800, 700);
        exit.setBackground(Color.red);
        exit.setForeground(Color.white);



        JButton select1 = new JButton("Select 1");
        JButton select2 = new JButton("Select 2");
        JButton select3 = new JButton("Select 3");
        JButton select4 = new JButton("Select 4");
        JButton select5 = new JButton("Select 5");
        JButton RS1 = new JButton();
        JButton back = new JButton("Back");
        back.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        back.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        select1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));         

        RS1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        RS1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        RS1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        RS1.setVisible(false);
        RS1.setOpaque(false);
        RS1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        RS1.setBorderPainted(false);    
        RS1.setVisible(false);
        RS1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }});
//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        select1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                RS1.setVisible(true);
                int select1student1 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10 + 1);
                if (select1student1 == 1) {
                    RS1.setText("Student One");
                }
                if (select1student1 == 2) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Two");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 3) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Three");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 4) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Four");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 5) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Five");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 6) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Six");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 7) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Seven");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 8) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Eight");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 9) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Nine");
                }

                if (select1student1 == 10) {
                    RS1.setText("Student Ten");
                }





            }});

        select2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        select2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }});

        select3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        select3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }});

        select4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        select4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }});

        select5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
        select5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        select5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }});

        select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                select.setVisible(false);
                absent.setVisible(false);
                exit.setVisible(false);
                display.remove(select);
                display.remove(absent);
                display.remove(exit);
                back.setVisible(true);
                display.add(back);
                display.add(select1);
                display.add(select2);
                display.add(select3);
                display.add(select4);
                display.add(select5);
                display.add(RS1);
                select1.setVisible(true);
                select2.setVisible(true);
                select3.setVisible(true);
                select4.setVisible(true);
                select5.setVisible(true);
                back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        RS1.setText("");
                        RS1.setVisible(false);
                        display.add(select);
                        display.add(absent);
                        display.add(exit);                          
                        display.remove(back);
                        select1.setVisible(false);
                        select2.setVisible(false);
                        select3.setVisible(false);
                        select4.setVisible(false);
                        select5.setVisible(false);
                        select.setVisible(true);
                        display.remove(select1);
                        display.remove(select2);
                        display.remove(select3);
                        display.remove(select4);
                        display.remove(select5);

                        absent.setVisible(true);
                        exit.setVisible(true);
                        back.setVisible(false);


                    }

                });

            }});


        //Mark Absents
        //
        //
        //
        //
        absent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton back = new JButton("Back");
                back.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                back.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));

                //Mark The Absentees Below

                JButton AB1 = new JButton("Student 1");
                AB1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB2 = new JButton("Student 2");
                AB2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB3 = new JButton("Student 3");
                AB3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB4 = new JButton("Student 4");
                AB4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB5 = new JButton("Student 5");
                AB5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB6 = new JButton("Student 6");
                AB6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB6.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB7 = new JButton("Student 7");
                AB7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB8 = new JButton("Student 8");
                AB8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB9 = new JButton("Student 9");
                AB9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB10 = new JButton("Student 10");
                AB10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB10.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB11 = new JButton("Student 11");
                AB11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB11.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB12 = new JButton("Student 12");
                AB12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB12.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB13 = new JButton("Student 13");
                AB13.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB13.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB14 = new JButton("Student 14");
                AB14.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB14.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB15 = new JButton("Student 15");
                AB15.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB15.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB16 = new JButton("Student 16");
                AB16.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB16.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB17 = new JButton("Student 17");
                AB17.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB17.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB18 = new JButton("Student 18");
                AB18.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB18.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB19 = new JButton("Student 19");
                AB19.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB19.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB20 = new JButton("Student 20");
                AB20.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB20.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB21 = new JButton("Student 21");
                AB21.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB21.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                JButton AB22 = new JButton("Student 22");
                AB22.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,100));
                AB22.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));

                AB1.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB2.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB3.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB4.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB5.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB6.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB7.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB8.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB9.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB10.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB11.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB12.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB13.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB14.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB15.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB16.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB17.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB18.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB19.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB20.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB21.setBackground(Color.green);
                AB22.setBackground(Color.green);


                select.setVisible(false);
                absent.setVisible(false);
                exit.setVisible(false);
                display.remove(select);
                display.remove(absent);
                display.remove(exit);
                back.setVisible(true);
                display.add(back);
                display.add(AB1);
                display.add(AB2);
                display.add(AB3);
                display.add(AB4);
                display.add(AB5);
                display.add(AB6);
                display.add(AB7);
                display.add(AB8);
                display.add(AB9);
                display.add(AB10);      
                display.add(AB11);  
                display.add(AB12);  
                display.add(AB13);  
                display.add(AB14);  
                display.add(AB15);  
                display.add(AB16);  
                display.add(AB17);  
                display.add(AB18);  
                display.add(AB19);  
                display.add(AB20);  
                display.add(AB21);  
                display.add(AB22);  


                AB1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
//********************************************************************
                    String AB1Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB1Status) {
                        case "Present": AB1.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB1Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB1.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB1Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB2Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB2Status) {
                        case "Present": AB2.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB2Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB2.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB2Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB3Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB3Status) {
                        case "Present": AB3.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB3Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB3.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB3Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB4Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB4Status) {
                        case "Present": AB4.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB4Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB4.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB4Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB5Status = "Present"; 
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB5Status) {
                        case "Present": AB5.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB5Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB5.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB5Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB6Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB6Status) {
                        case "Present": AB6.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB6Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB6.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB6Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB7Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB7Status) {
                        case "Present": AB7.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB7Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB7.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB7Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB8Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB8Status) {
                        case "Present": AB8.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB8Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB8.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB8Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB9Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB9Status) {
                        case "Present": AB9.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB9Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB9.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB9Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB10Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB10Status) {
                        case "Present": AB10.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB10Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB10.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB10Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB11Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB11Status) {
                        case "Present": AB11.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB11Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB11.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB11Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB12Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB12Status) {
                        case "Present": AB12.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB12Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB12.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB12Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB13Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB13Status) {
                        case "Present": AB13.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB13Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB13.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB13Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB14Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB14Status) {
                        case "Present": AB14.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB14Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB14.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB14Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB15.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB15Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB15Status) {
                        case "Present": AB15.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB15Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB15.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB15Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB16.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB16Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB16Status) {
                        case "Present": AB16.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB16Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB16.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB16Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB17.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB17Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB17Status) {
                        case "Present": AB17.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB17Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB17.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB17Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB18.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB18Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB18Status) {
                        case "Present": AB18.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB18Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB18.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB18Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB19.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB19Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB19Status) {
                        case "Present": AB19.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB19Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB19.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB19Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB20.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB20Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB20Status) {
                        case "Present": AB20.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB20Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB20.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB20Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB21.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB21Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB21Status) {
                        case "Present": AB21.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB21Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB21.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB21Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});
                AB22.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    String AB22Status = "Present";
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        switch(AB22Status) {
                        case "Present": AB22.setBackground(Color.red);
                        AB22Status = "Absent"; break;
                        case "Absent": AB22.setBackground(Color.green);
                        AB22Status = "Present"; break;
                        }}});





                back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        display.add(select);
                        display.add(absent);
                        display.add(exit);                          
                        AB1.setVisible(false);
                        AB2.setVisible(false);
                        AB3.setVisible(false);
                        AB4.setVisible(false);
                        AB5.setVisible(false);
                        AB6.setVisible(false);
                        AB7.setVisible(false);
                        AB8.setVisible(false);
                        AB9.setVisible(false);
                        AB10.setVisible(false);
                        AB11.setVisible(false);
                        AB12.setVisible(false);
                        AB13.setVisible(false);
                        AB14.setVisible(false);
                        AB15.setVisible(false);
                        AB16.setVisible(false);
                        AB17.setVisible(false);
                        AB18.setVisible(false);
                        AB19.setVisible(false);
                        AB20.setVisible(false);
                        AB21.setVisible(false);
                        AB22.setVisible(false);
                        select.setVisible(true);                        
                        display.remove(back);
                        display.remove(AB1);
                        display.remove(AB2);
                        display.remove(AB3);
                        display.remove(AB4);
                        display.remove(AB5);
                        display.remove(AB6);
                        display.remove(AB7);
                        display.remove(AB8);
                        display.remove(AB9);
                        display.remove(AB10);
                        display.remove(AB11);
                        display.remove(AB12);
                        display.remove(AB13);
                        display.remove(AB14);
                        display.remove(AB15);
                        display.remove(AB16);
                        display.remove(AB17);
                        display.remove(AB18);
                        display.remove(AB19);
                        display.remove(AB20);
                        display.remove(AB21);
                        display.remove(AB22);
                        display.remove(back);


                        absent.setVisible(true);
                        exit.setVisible(true);
                        back.setVisible(false);




                    }});
            }});



        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }});
        display.setVisible(true);   
        display.add(select);
        display.add(absent);
        display.add(exit);
    }}
```

Comment: SO rules exist for a reason, if it does not allow you to post your question for whatever reason, instead of trying to disregard it, try to understand why it is saying so and how could you improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is in a different package you should import the package and make the variable `public static`, if is in the same package making it `public static` should work, and you can access it like `ClassName.variableName`, className being your class, and variableName being your variable name.

Util.class

```
public static int x = 5;
```

Other.classes

```
Util.x = 10;
```

`Util.x` is now 10

you can access it or change it like this.

Comment: I would do this, however I need the value to be able to change

Comment: you can change it from everywhere. do not write "final" and you are good to go

Comment: Can you give me an example code or modify my code cause I don't really understand what you mean. Thanks though